# Does " Treat the people as you want to be treated" make sense

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I was listening to a speech and then I found a sentence:

> Treat the people ***as*** you want to be treated.

I think the sentence doesn't make sense. The correct one would be:
Treat the people ***how*** you want to be treated.

Am I correct?I might be wrong. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "The people" is commonly used politically to refer to the population of a country ("We the people of the United States..."). In your case you can probably omit "the" and just say "Treat people...".

Comment: I'm afraid you _are_ wrong. A traditional phrase expressing the same idea is [Do as you would be done by](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do-as-you-would-be-done-by).

Answer (score 1):

"As" is a functional word in English, and has a wide range of uses.  Here it functions as a conjunction, and has the meaning "in the same way that".

This is the primary meaning of "as".  It carries a sense of "two things are similar in degree, manner, time, or consequence".

"How" can be used as a conjunction ("I remember how I solved the puzzle") to mean explicitly "the manner in which", so "how" would be a possible alternative to "as".  But whereas "as" is commonly a conjunction or preposition, "how" is normally a question word. So I prefer the sentence with "as".

Comment: What's the difference between "Do as I say" and "Do what I say"?

Comment: The first is an idiom meaning "follow my my instructions" and often contrasted with "...not as I do."